# How to handle javascript content and redirects after successful weblogin SSO authentication?

Tags: python, authentication, single-sign-on, python-requests, qtwebkit

I am writing a python script that downloads class content(mp4, pdf) from my school website. My school uses Weblogin SSO authentication to access any of their protected urls.

I was able to authenticate my credentials using the first part of the script below:

```
#1. Authenticate
login_url = "https://weblogin.MY_SCHOOL.edu/login"
payload = {'login':'my_loging','password':'my_pass'}
target_url = "https://My_SCHOOL.instructure.com/courses/12345678""

with requests.Session() as c: 
    req_headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36}'}
    c.headers.update(req_headers)
    c.get(login_url) # to get cookies
    c.post(url1, data=payload) #,headers = req_headers)

#2. get html from target site
    W1 = c.get(target_url)
    print(W1.url)
    print(W1.text)

#3. parse html and download content.
    #tbc
```

I can see that my authentication was successful in c.post.text, but whenver I try to access any of the target sites using get() in same requests.session(), I don't get the expected html content for my class, but rather a message that reads:

> "Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the
>   Continue button once to proceed"

And the target URL redirects to this url:

> "https://idp.MY_SCHOOL.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO"

Why am I not able to access the target url(s) after a successful SSO authentication? I am not sure if javascript support in the requests module is the issue here because even when I disable JS support in my internet browser, I am able to see some html content of the target_url, albeit not all of it. It seems strange that my get() request gets stuck in the redirected url: "https:.../SAML2/Redirect/SSO"

I would appreciate any pointers on how to go around this issue. I wouldn't want to use webdrivers such as selenium or mechanize. I have used QtWebkit to render Javascript content, but I don't know if it is even possible to transfer my  authentication cookies from my request.session() to QtWebkit.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The code is embedded in my question. I don't know what else you need...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in SSO but I think I know what's going on. In a typical situation, your browser will post your login credentials to the login url.  The response will be an html page containing a form.  The form will contain your SSO token.  Within the html page, embedded javascript will submit the form to the application you are trying to access. The application will validate the token and then grant you access.  When javascript in enabled, this happens seamlessly.  If you turn off javascript in your browser and try to login, you will the same message and you will have to press a button in order to submit the form containing your token.  To do this via script,  you will have to likely have to parse the form, get the token value, and then post it yourself.

Comment: Thanks James for your comment. I think that is what's going on here. Do you know how could I go about parsing the form to get the token value and posting it myself? I don't think I can do that with request.session().